# Get the Dimension of a Node - JavaFX 2

Tags: java, javafx-2

I am trying to jump to JavaFX from Swing. But I can't find how to get the width and the height of a node.

So, here is a bit of code.

```
Label label = new Label();
label.setText("Hello");
label.setFont(new Font(32));

System.out.println(label.getPrefWidth());
System.out.println(label.getWidth());
System.out.println(label.getMinWidth());
System.out.println(label.getMaxWidth());
```

The results are:

```
-1.0
 0.0
-1.0
-1.0
```

The same thing in Swing is:

```
JComponent.getPreferredSize().width
JComponent.getPreferredSize().height
```

Thank you

---

After edit:

Why this isn't working for me?

```
public class Dimensions extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new MyPanel(), 500, 500));
        primaryStage.centerOnScreen();
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

```
public class MyPanel extends Pane {

    public MyPanel() {  
        Label label = new Label();
        label.setText("Hello");
        label.setFont(new Font(32));

        getChildren().add(label);

        label.relocate(150, 150);

        System.out.println(label.getWidth());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Width and height are not initialized until you put node in a container actually placed on the scene, because they can change depending on container type.

Try next:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Label label = new Label();
    label.setText("Hello");
    label.setFont(Font.font("Arial", 32));

    System.out.println(label.getWidth());

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(label);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    System.out.println("------");
    System.out.println(label.getWidth());
}
```

In your code make next changes:

```
public class Dimensions extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        launch(args);
    }

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        MyPanel myPanel = new MyPanel();
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(myPanel, 500, 500));
        primaryStage.show();

        System.out.println(myPanel.label.getWidth());
    }
}

class MyPanel extends Pane {
    public Label label;

    public MyPanel() {

        label = new Label();
        label.setText("Hello");
        label.setFont(new Font(32));
        getChildren().add(label);
        label.relocate(150, 150);
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited my first post because it still isn't working for me. I don't know how to answer my post again without editing it as it is my first post here. Thanks for helping.

Comment: for the same reason. You are calling `label.getWidth()` before it was placed on scene. I've added corrected code sample.

Comment: Yes, I understood completely the logic behind this. Thank you Sergey.

Answer (score 20):

Once the node is added to the screen you can use:

```
thisNode.getBoundsInParent().getHeight(); //Returns height of object in parent container.
```